# Jest coverage testing global objects and inverse condition

Tags: unit-testing, global-variables, jestjs

I've got a global object on `window` that has a function. In my code I'm writing this:

```
if (window.foo) {
      window.foo.bar();
}
```

In the tests, when `window.foo` has a value I assert that `window.foo.bar` has been called. Easy enough.

Jest coverage is complaining that I'm not testing the negative value, i.e. when `window.foo` is undefined. But I've been struggling to work out what to assert on.

What I'd like to do - is mock `window.foo` and assert that it is only called once, when we check whether it has a value or is undefined (i.e. the call to `window.foo.bar` is never made.

I'm trying to mock the global window object and return an object but I'm getting confused as to how to mock and spyOn a value when it isn't a function, and then check it has been accessed.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a getter so whenever a property in the object is being accessed inside the getter we could run multiple actions, in our case we just trigger our spy manually.

```
describe('window.foo', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    delete global.foo // make sure you clean your global object after each test
  })

  it('should be called twice', () => {
    const fooSpy = jest.fn();
    const barSpy = jest.fn();
    Object.defineProperty(global, 'foo', {
      configurable: true, // very important or else you can't delete
      get() {
        fooSpy(); //we manually call our spy so we can assert later

        // and we return an object with another spy for our bar function
        return { bar: barSpy};
      }
    });

    if (global.foo) {
      global.foo.bar()
    }


    expect(fooSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
    expect(barSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });

  it('should be called once', () => {
    const fooSpy = jest.fn();
    Object.defineProperty(global, 'foo', {
      writconfigurableable: true,
      get() {
        fooSpy(); // we trigger the spy manually

        // we return undefined
        return undefined;
      }
    });

    if (global.foo) {
      global.foo.bar()
    }


    expect(fooSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

You can see it working in [here](https://repl.it/repls/LeadingStrongRhombus)